# UITableView with Sections as Date from Json Data

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I am working on table view to render some data received after JSON parsing. I want my table view to have sections based on different dates. Each record in JSON is an event and multiple events can take place on single date.

Here is my JSON data
https://get.rosterbuster.com/wp-content/uploads/dummy-response.json

I want to render my table view like this
[Table View with Sections as Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSoWi.png)

**What I have done sofar:**

I have parsed the data in following Structure

```
struct Roster : Codable {

    let flightnr: String?
    let date: String?
    let aircraftType: String?
    let tail: String?
    let departure: String?
    let destination: String?
    let departTime: String?
    let arrivalTime: String?
    let dutyID: String?
    let dutyCode: String?
    let captain: String?
    let firstOfficer: String?
    let flightAttendant: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case flightnr = "Flightnr"
        case date = "Date"
        case aircraftType = "Aircraft Type"
        case tail = "Tail"
        case departure = "Departure"
        case destination = "Destination"
        case departTime = "Time_Depart"
        case arrivalTime = "Time_Arrive"
        case dutyID = "DutyID"
        case dutyCode = "DutyCode"
        case captain = "Captain"
        case firstOfficer = "First Officer"
        case flightAttendant = "Flight Attendant"
    }  
}
```

I have also setup basic table view but don't know how to group the retrieved data into different sections as per the image I have attached above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any local storage like core data. If so you could use `NSFetchedResultsController` where you can group by a particular field. If not you would have to do by yourself by using `UITableviewDataSource` methods to determine number of sections and content of each row in the section

Comment: Yes I am using core data persistence. Any good tutorial on NSFetchedResultsController that can serve my purpose?

Comment: IMHO, take the time read the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller. The `NSFetchedResultsController` has an initialiser which takes `sectionNameKeyPath` as an argument. Specify the field name you would like to group by. Go step by step, do a sample project with basics before jumping into your specific problem

Comment: Thanks a lot for documentation. I will try it now.

Comment: @user1046037 I tried with following tutorial and its working great.

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/05/displaying-data-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift/

Thanks a lot again for all your help :)

Comment: Cool, Glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I'd suggest:

1) **get number of sections by mapping the API JSON** response in a set based on the date property. Here's something you could use (maybe you don't need to cast it in Array as well and you want to check if date is not nil)

```
self.sections = Array(Set(self.dataModel.map({ (roster) -> String in
                roster.date!
            })))
```

2) **set your rowsPerSection** data model by creating an array of Roster for each section.

```
//first set the array of sections.count dimension and empty array for each item
self.sections.forEach({ (string) in
    self.rowsPerSection.append([])
})
//then set each array
for index in 0..<self.sections.count {
    self.dataModel.forEach({ (roster) in
      if roster.date == self.sections[index] {
          self.rowsPerSection[index].append(roster)
        }
    })
}
```

This is my dummy code, I tested it with your URL and it works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var dataModel = [Roster]()
    var sections = [String]()
    var rowsPerSection = [[Roster]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        APICall { (rosters) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dataModel = rosters!
                self.sections = Array(Set(self.dataModel.map({ (roster) ->     String in
                roster.date!
                })))

                //first set the array of sections.count dimension and empty array for each item
                self.sections.forEach({ (string) in
                    self.rowsPerSection.append([])
                })
                //then set each array
                for index in 0..<self.sections.count {
                    self.dataModel.forEach({ (roster) in
                        if roster.date == self.sections[index] {
                            self.rowsPerSection[index].append(roster)
                        }
                    })
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func APICall(onSuccess: @escaping(_ response: [Roster]?) -> Void) {
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            let url = URL(string: "https://get.rosterbuster.com/wp-content/uploads/dummy-response.json")!
            let requestURL = URLRequest(url: url)
            let session = URLSession.shared
            session.dataTask(with: requestURL) { (data, response, error) in
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let responseJson = try! decoder.decode([Roster].self, from: data!)
                onSuccess(responseJson)
                group.leave()
                }.resume()
            group.wait()
            return
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        for index in 0..<sections.count {
            if index == section {
                return rowsPerSection[index].count
            }
        }
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = rowsPerSection[indexPath.section] [indexPath.row].destination

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }
}
```

Here's the screenshot -> [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB6zZ.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have done a great job. It’s really very helpful.